# Pygame Lever Images Display On Key Click Problem

Tags: python, pygame

so I have a lever image with 3 different directions my problem is when I  use the ***if [pygame.K_p]*** mutliple times I want to switch between the defferent images but heres my problem [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/d1be4a44d61c84e97bd2fc0c2336eac7) when I click p it display right and the middle one but not the left one and I have to hold the p for some reason to switch it I want it so when I click p 1 time it switches direction of my lever.

In My Main Loop here what I have done  for the first one I said if we click p then move1 should be True then if my move1 is true then it should switch my direction of my lever image to right one then my next one of my image is
on the right and we click p again it should switch my image back to 1 the middle one and like repeat
I am not sure if I am doing correctly but yeah

switch1 is the ***left** switch2 is the ***middle*** switch3 ***right one***

```
    if keys[pygame.K_p]:
        move1 = True
        move2 = False


    
    if keys[pygame.K_p]:
        if switch1.direction == "switch3":
            move1 = False
            move2 = True


    if switch1.direction == "switch3" or switch1.direction == "switch1":
        if keys[pygame.K_p]:
            switch1.direction = "switch2"
            if switch1.direction == "switch2":
                move1 = False
                move2 = False
            
    if move1:
        move2 = False
        switch1.direction = "switch3"

        if rop1.y <= 200:
            rop1.y += 2

        else:
            rop1.direction = "nomove"


    if move2:
        move1 = False
        switch1.direction = "switch1"


        if rop1.y <= 200:
            rop1.y -= 2

        else:
            rop1.direction = "nomove"
```

I am looking for a way to switch my levers with 1 keybind "p" left right or middle repeat Thank You!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task you have to use the `KEYDOWN` event instead of `pygame.key.get_pressed()`.

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a sequence with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement.

The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released. Use the keyboard events for a single action or a step-by-step movement.

---

Create a list of "switch" Surface. Use a variable to store the index of the current "switch" Surface (`current_switch`). An additional variable (`current_move` ) that indicates whether the index needs to be increased or decreased when <kbd>p</kbd> is pressed.

`current_switch` can have the values 0, 1 or 2. 0 means left, 1 is middle and 2 is right. `current_move` is either -1 or 1. If `current_move` is -1, the switch moves to the left when <kbd>p</kbd> is pressed. If `current_move` is 1, the switch moves to the right when "p" is pressed. When the switch reaches the left or right position, the `current_move` must be changed:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

files = ['switch_left.png', 'switch_middle.png', 'switch_right.png'] 
switches = [pygame.image.load(f) for f in files]
current_switch = 0
current_move = 1

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                
                if current_switch == 0: 
                    current_move = 1
                elif current_switch == len(switches)-1: 
                    current_move = -1
                current_switch += current_move

    window.fill(0)
    swtich_image = switches[current_switch]
    window.blit(swtich_image, swtich_image.get_rect(midbottom = (100, 150)))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: last say I want to move something when my switch is on the right  would I say if curren_switch == 0: then my code below and also there are 0 1 2  switches right?

Comment: @HabibIsmail `current_switch` can have the values 0, 1 or 2. 0 is left, 1 is middle and 2 is right. `current_move` is either -1 or 1. If `current_move` is -1 the switch will move to the left when "p" is pressed. If `current_move` is 1 the switch will move to the right when "p" is pressed.